# content type json, safe for dealing with private data?

Tags: ajax, json, codeigniter

So I read an interesting  [article](http://directwebremoting.org/blog/joe/2007/03/05/json_is_not_as_safe_as_people_think_it_is.html)
a while back and I would like to get some feedback from the CI community on how you would deal with private data such as email addresses, permissions any user data considered private.

Public data is fine as I can control the final output so its less of a security problem.

**Below** is the way I would pull all the public data for say my users, really what I want to know how safe is using the same approach for private data under 
an admin controller(output is json);

*Ajax request for the frontend (users.js)  I like to create a new js file for each module for development purposes, then compile.*

```
(function($){

    var userObj = {
        init: function(){

            if(document.getElementById(id)){
                this.populateUserData();
            }
        },
        populateUserData : function(){
            //for demonstration purposes let build output into a table
            $.ajax({
                url : BASE_PATH + 'users/get_active_users',
                dataType : 'json',
                success : function(callback){

                    if(callback.status === 'ok')
                    {
                        var output = "";
                        $.each(callback.users, function(){

                            var $this = this;
                            output += '<tr>'
                            output += '<td>'+$this.firstname+'</td>';
                            output += '<td>'+$this.lastname+'</td>';
                            output += '<td>'+$this.alias+'</td>';
                            output += '<td>'+$this.joined.date+'</td>';
                            output += '</tr>'

                        });
                        output += "</tr>";
                        $("table#id tbody").append(output);
                    }

                }
            });
        }
    }

    $(function(){
        userObj.init();
    });


})(jQuery);
```

*The html (lets build some dummy data)*

```
<table class="bordered" id="id">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Firstname</th>
            <th>Lastname</th>
            <th>Alias</th>
            <th>Joined</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        //rendered out via js
    </tbody>
</table>
```

*Controller request*

```
if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Users extends MY_Controller {

    public function __construct() {parent::__construct();}

    public function get_active_users()
    {
        if($this->input->is_ajax_request())
        {
            //grab all the active users(php-activerecord)
            $users = User::get_all_active_users();

            //render the ouput content type as json
            $this->output
                  ->set_content_type('application/json')
                  ->set_output(json_encode($users));
        }
        else
        {
            show_404();
        }
    }
```

*Activerecord model*

```
if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
exit('No direct script access allowed');

class User extends ActiveRecord\Model {

     public static function get_all_active_users()
     {
         $users = self::find('all', array('conditions' => array('active=?', (int) 1)));

         if($users)
         {
             foreach($users as $user){

                $date = explode('-', date('F jS, Y - G:i', strtotime($user->created_at)));

                $ret[] = array(
                    'joined'    =>  array(
                        'date'  =>  $date[0],
                        'time'  =>  $date[1]
                    ),
                    'firstname' =>  $user->firstname,
                    'lastname'  =>  $user->lastname,
                    'alias' =>  $user->alias
                );
             }

             return array(
                'status'    =>  'ok',
                'users' =>  $ret
             );
         }
         else
         {
             //do something else
         }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter what content type you use (JSON, XML, etc.).  You should only send private data if it's encrypted.  Even if your controller is secured to certain users, it still doesn't matter.  Only send private data over the wire if it's encrypted.

Comment: Thats fine for passwords, emails etc, however if I want to show public attributes within a private admin scope such as groups, permissions, how would I deal with this data?  ie: permissions (["r", "u", "d", "a", "s"])

Comment: @Philip I'm not quite sure what you're asking.  There's nothing inherently sensitive about sending an array of permissions over the wire, so long as those permissions can't be faked by sending a "fake" request (the "sanitize your inputs" rule would apply here) it should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

As far as security goes using JSON is no different than any other AJAX-based implementation.